Trying to run some logic only at the Open of the 1st candle of the Regular Trading Day
I'm tyring to run some logic only at the open of the market.  I tried to use the built in functions of barstate.isfirst and barstate.isnew but I'm finding that it keeps running until the first bar is closed, which for me is a 30-minute time frame.  I'm also finding some instability with these built in functions with repainting etc so wanted to know if there is another way to do this.  Some stocks have lower volume and don't start trading properly for a minute or so, and I have other logic in my algo that applies to all other times but not at the open, upon the very first print of the regular trading day.
I tried in the built in functions for Bar States.

//@version=5
indicator("Testing Open Logic", shorttitle="Trend Cont - Gap Logic", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

if session.isfirstbar
    label.new(bar_index[0], close, "New Bar")  

if barstate.isnew
    label.new(bar_index[0], close + 2,"BSIN",  color = color.purple)

if barstate.isfirst
    label.new(bar_index[0], close + 3, "IFB",color = color.teal)


try session.isfirstbar_regular

Please share you code you with a minimal reproducible example

I will try session.isfirstbar_regular, but will it not keep triggering until the close of the 1st bar?

without code, we can't help you

please don't post your code as an image

Sorry, posted the code above

session.isfirstbar_regular
Returns true on the first regular session bar of the day, false otherwise. The result is the same whether extended session information is used or not.
//@version=5
indicator("Testing Open Logic", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

if session.isfirstbar_regular
    label.new(bar_index[0], close + 3, "IFB",color = color.teal)

test imagen

Yes that's correct, but it will keep running the logic as long as it's true on the 1st bar, it won't just execute it once and then stop running. For example if it gaps up I want to run different logic than if there is no gap. If it gaps up it will trigger my new buy or sell, but if it fills the gap right after then it will trigger the other logic that isn't for a gap. So I just need it to run one time when it triggers. I tried using a flag but it just keeps executing the if statements on the 1st candle.

I tried added a flag to it too so the loop only runs once but for some reason it just ignores it and keeps running.
